# query a datetime column by date only

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Here i have a column which is in datetime format.I want to search the table by a given daterange.But the query i wrote is generating an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '**14:27:12) AND date(2016-06-28 14:27:12) LIMIT 0, 30**' at line 1

```
SELECT * FROM `tele_incoming_call` WHERE DATE(`incoming_call_date`) BETWEEN date(2016-06-27 14:27:12) AND 
date(2016-06-28 14:27:12)
```

Comment: ... escape the date

Comment: try enclosing your date values inside single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found that the following sql works for me

```
SELECT * FROM `tele_incoming_call` WHERE `incoming_call_date` BETWEEN '2016-06-27' AND 
'2016-06-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `date` and quote the times.

```
SELECT * FROM `tele_incoming_call` WHERE (incoming_call_date BETWEEN '2016-06-27 14:27:12' AND '2016-06-28 14:27:12')
```

Comment: i want to search by date,,search a datetime column by date only.that was the question....

Comment: You state that `incoming_call_date` is a datetime column. Then this is what you need or I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tele_incoming_call` WHERE MONTH(`incoming_call_date`) BETWEEN MONTH(2016-06-27 14:27:12) AND 
MONTH(2016-06-28 14:27:12) AND YEAR(`incoming_call_date`) BETWEEN YEAR(2016-06-27 14:27:12) AND 
YEAR(2016-06-28 14:27:12) AND DAY(`incoming_call_date`) BETWEEN DAY(2016-06-27 14:27:12) AND 
DAY(2016-06-28 14:27:12)
```

but better is

```
SELECT * FROM `tele_incoming_call` WHERE `incoming_call_date` BETWEEN '2016-06-27 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score -1):

`date(2016-06-27 14:27:12)` within MySQL query is wrong.
 Update the Query to the following.

```
$sql_query="SELECT *
FROM `tele_incoming_call`
WHERE DATE(`incoming_call_date`) 
BETWEEN ".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2016-06-27 14:27:12'))." AND 
".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2016-06-28 14:27:12'));
```

To get the get from String we can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) which converts the given string to **Unix timestamp**.
 And then we pass that timestamp to [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the date in required `Y-m-d` format to compare in MySQL.

---

**Update:**

You can make use of [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) MySQL function to compare dates only.

So your query will look like this,

```
$sql_query="SELECT *
FROM `tele_incoming_call`
WHERE DATE(`incoming_call_date`) 
BETWEEN DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2016-06-28 14:27:12','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d') AND 
DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2016-06-28 14:28:12','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d')";
```

Comment: No, you cannot mix freely SQL and PHP. They're entirely different languages.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to concatenate the string. Updated the answer.